# req.body undefined or empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, express

I have to two controllers and two separate routers.
bookController.js is work perfectly. Now I created userControllers to handle registration and login logic but req.body is empty. I tried to console.log to see if the form is being passed. but I get empty or undefined

I don't know what I am doing or what I have done wrong

Thanks

This is the app.js

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
//const csurf = require('csurf');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var methodOverride = require('method-override')
//const multer = require('multer'); 

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
var bookRouter = require('./routes/book');


//Cross site request forgery
//const csrfMiddleware = csurf({cookie: true});

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(cookieParser());
//app.use(csrfMiddleware);
app.use(methodOverride('_method'))
//app.use(multerConfig );

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
app.use('/', bookRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

usersControllers.js

```
const knex = require('../model/connection');

exports.register = function(req, res)
{
    //REGISTER USER FORM PAGE
    res.render('user/register');

}

exports.registeruser = function(req, res, next)
{
    //REGISTER USER HANDLE
    console.log(req.body.username);
    console.log(req.body.email);
    console.log(req.body.password);
    console.log(req.body.password1);
    res.render('user/dashboard');
}
```

and this is routes/users.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var usersControllers = require('../controllers/usersControllers');

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/dashboard', usersControllers.index); 
router.get('/register', usersControllers.register); 
router.get('/login', usersControllers.login); 
router.post('/registeruser', usersControllers.registeruser); 


module.exports = router;
```

This is the form

```
<%- include('../includes/layout'); %>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3"></div>
<div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header bg-primary"> Create User </div>
           <form id="c_form-h" class="" method="post" action="/users/registeruser" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="padding: 5px;">  


          <div class="form-group row">
               <label for="username" class="col-6 col-form-label">Username</label>
           <div class="col-12">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Add UserName"> 
          </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="email" class="col-6 col-form-label">Email</label>
            <div class="col-12">
               <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Add Email"> 
           </div>
           </div>

           <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="password" class="col-6 col-form-label">Password</label>
            <div class="col-12">
               <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password"> 
           </div>
           </div>

           <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="password1" class="col-6 col-form-label">Password</label>
            <div class="col-12">
               <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password1" placeholder="Enter Password Again"> 
           </div>
           </div>
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3"></div>
</div>
</div>
      <%- include('../includes/footer'); %>
```

Comment: Please read [mcve]

Comment: I got to fix the error from github https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser/issues/345.

`sorry, you're having trouble and thanks for the information you provided. Your is set to use multipart/form-data but this module does not support that type of form. You'll need to use a different module for multipart forms. You can find a list of these at the top of the readme: https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#body-parser`

Answer (score 0):

Let’s try to keep this least technical.

Let’s say you are sending a html form data to node-js server i.e. you made a request to the server. The server file would receive your request under a request object. Now by logic, if you console log this request object in your server file you should see your form data some where in it, which could be extracted then, but whoa ! you actually don’t !

So, where is our data ? How will we extract it if its not only present in my request.

Simple explanation to this is http sends your form data in bits and pieces which are intended to get assembled as they reach their destination. So how would you extract your data.
Use something called “body-parser” which would do this for you.

body-parser parses your request and converts it into a format from which you can easily extract relevant information that you may need.
First of all require the following in your app.js file.

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
```

and add the following line to make it work

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. I understand what you have explained. I have included the bodyParser and use it just as you have said. But the problem persists. I am getting this `{}
POST /users/registeruser 200 87.037 ms - 20`. I have other post items form and edit forms that are working perfectly. I dont know why this not working

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer: Although, you have data coming in URL, you've no way to use that data. Use bocy-parser package to fix this issue.

```
npm install body-parser --save
```

This installs the body-parser package. What this does is that it binds together the response data sent back so you can actually get to it and use it. Without it, you're just getting data to an endpoint without any way to use it.

Use the body parser like this:

```
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

Then inside the function where you try to use the data back do something like

```
console.log(req.body.username);
console.log(req.body.email);
console.log(req.body.password);
console.log(req.body.password1);
```

I understand you already tried to implement the body-parser as you said above. Try making a separate endpoint for this. Instead of /users/registeruser, try doing this in a separate /registeruser endpoint and see if that works out. If it does, try again with some insight in endpoints setup, if not, comment further.